# Open the network list with command line

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm working with a Pi running Raspbian. Is there a way to open the network list with a command from the terminal? This is the list I mean:

[image: Screenshot of Wi-Fi network list]

I have searched in the file `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` is defined the menu bar (sizes, icons, applications, etc ...). I think this is the code that defines the icon:

```
Plugin { 
 type=dhcpcdui
  Config { } 
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to get around not having a mouse and open the list as if you had clicked it with a mouse or do you want to list the available networks via the command line?

Comment: Yes, to open it without the mouse.

Comment: What will that give you that you can't from Darth Vader's answer below? Anything you can do with the applet you can do from the commandline (which does not require a mouse).

Comment: Yes, I can modify the file that has named me 'Darth Vader', but the problem is that I can not find the command that I have to execute to display the list of networks.

Comment: it is the first command in Darth Vader's answer iwlist wlan0 scan. This may also help https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: But I want it with a command is to show the window of the list of networks. Do not console the networks, if not in the window. The image I put in the p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Which will show a list of available Wi-Fi networks.

If you are connected to a network already you can see a list of the other devices on the network with:

```
nmap
```

To launch the terminal using a keyboard you can create a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. To do this first run:

```
nano ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
```

This will allow you to modify the `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` file.

Anywhere between the `<keyboard>` and `</keyboard>` tags add:

```
<!-- Launch terminal when ctr-alt-t is pressed -->
  <keybind key="C-A-t">
    <action name="Execute"><command>lxterminal</command></action>
  </keybind>
```

If you put this piece of code just before the `</keyboard>` tag it should look something like this:

```
<!-- Launch gnome-screenshot when Print is pressed -->
  <keybind key="Print">
    <action name="Execute"><command>gnome-screenshot</command></action>
  </keybind>
<!-- Launch terminal when ctr-alt-t is pressed -->
  <keybind key="C-A-t">
    <action name="Execute"><command>lxterminal</command></action>
  </keybind>
</keyboard>
```

Comment: What I am looking for is to open the dialog of the list of networks by command, to be able to execute that command from a script of 'python'. And the problem is that I do not know which process I should launch.

Comment: If you want to script something reliably use the command line not the gui.

Comment: Weird thing, `iwlist wlan0 scan` shows **only** the network I am connected to, not all.

Comment: @Suncatcher Try running the command as root. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `iwlist` as root to get a fresh scan. It gives **a lot** of output. Here's a way to get just a list of available networks:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID
                ESSID:"Daisycat"
                ESSID:"AI Lab"
                ESSID:"E4A451"
                ESSID:"EB4E7F"
                ESSID:"Lan Solo"
                ESSID:"3FA29B"
                ESSID:"BaronTweet"
                ESSID:"E15F8D"
                ESSID:"Malik3199 2.4G"
                ESSID:""
```

From [the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist):

> Triggering scanning is a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results.